# Web3 python: how can I decode Input Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

using web3 (python3) I am trying to decode InputData of the BSC transaction as seen on BscScan
[image]

In some solutions I've found code below is being used:

```
import web3
from web3.contract import Contract
...
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddress), abi=abi)
contract.functions.decode_function_input(transaction.input)
```

However, the abi's doesn't seem to have this function "decode_function_input" defined, as I am getting an error:

```
"web3.exceptions.ABIFunctionNotFound: ("The function 'decode_function_input' was not found in this contract's abi. ", 'Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?')"
```

I am 100% that the abi is correct. Also, on BscScan contract raw view, the function 'decode_function_input' indeed is not present.

Any other solutions, how to decode the **Input Data**?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `contract.functions.decode_function_input`, it is `contract.decode_function_input()`

Comment: It seems that I've forgotten the include the correct syntax and error due to so many tries. I have the code as you specified, however, I am getting this error: "ValueError: Could not find any function with matching selector"

Comment: I've figured it out!!! I thought I need to use tokenAddress and ABI for the token in question, while it was the pancakeswap V2 router address that was actually required!